# Calculating the pdf and cdf of $X^2$ and $X^3$ with the pdf of $X$ given

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be a random variable with the density funtion:
>
> $$\phi_X(x)= \begin{cases} 6x(1-x) & \text{if } 0<x<1, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$
>
> Find the density and cumulative distribution for the random variable
>
> 1. $Z = X^2$.
> 2. $Z = X^3$.

Edited attempt:

1. $\phi_Z(z)= 3(1-\sqrt{z})$ if $0<z<1$, and $0$ otherwise. (some details of how to get to this point would be great).
2. $$\phi_Z(z)= \begin{cases} 6 \sqrt[3]{z}(1-\sqrt[3]{z})|\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{z^2}}| & \text{if } 0<z<1, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

Comment: So your attempt got you to $\phi_Z(z) = \ldots$, and now you would like details on how you got there?!

Comment: Please define "Attempt".

Comment: @TMM I applied fgp's method to part to to get the density function, but I am unable to get to the cummulative part. Any suggestions? I tried to integrate from $(- \infty, x)$, but it doesn't converge.

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and $f$ the density of a random variable $X$, you have for the density $f_g(x)$ of $f(X)$ that $$
  f_g(x) = f(g^{-1}(x))\left|{g^{-1}}'(x)\right|
$$
*if* the derivative ${g^{-1}}'$ of $g^{-1}$ exists, is continuous, and non-zero, almost everywhere. ($g^{-1}$ is the inverse of $g$, i.e. $g^{-1}(g(x))=x$)

In your case, you'll need $g(x)=x^2$.

Comment: How does that look for $Z=X^3$ on the edited part?