# calculating p.d.f for a random variable generated through a non-linear combination of known random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $a\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2),b\sim  N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2),\,\,\,c=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)}\sim p_c$, what is $p_c$ in terms of $\mu_1,\sigma_1,\mu_2,\sigma_2$? Given p.d.f of $a$, i can easily find out the p.d.f of $a^2$ using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382528/calculating-the-pdf-and-cdf-of-x2-and-x3-with-the-pdf-of-x-given?rq=1), similarly for $b^2$ but then they are no more Gaussian so how do i add them, let alone square-root them? Or else, simply take $d=a^2+b^2\sim p_d$ and find $p_d$ in terms of $\mu_1,\sigma_1,\mu_2,\sigma_2$.What is the general line of attack for such problems?

Comment: The random variables c and d are nonnegative with full probability, do you seriously think they are normal?

Comment: @Did Yup that was errory thinking on my part. i have corrected it.

Comment: You should supply information about dependence relations between a and b. Even assuming they are independent, i don't think you find and actual formula ( haven't done calculations tho). If you write $a=\sigma Z+\mu$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and $b$ similar, then we see that $a^2+b^2$ will be a sum of a gamma variable and a normal distributed variable. I don't think that this convulution has a closed form pdf.

be a sum of a normal distribution and a gamma distribution.
I haven't done any calculations though, so i can't be sure.

Comment: So is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$  constant? Maybe it is possible, if $a$ and $b$ are suitably dependent. So $a^2+b^2=p_c^2$, and now it should be quick.

Comment: @AndréNicolas No, they are independent, hence c is also a random variable whose p.d.f needs to be found.

Comment: if $a$ and $b$ are standard normal and independent, then you have a closed form and it is the Rayleigh distribution.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: Bur unfortunately the situation is not so pleasant  for general independent normals.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a non-central chi-distribution (NOT *chi-squared*). See the Wikipedia article for details;  $k = 2$, notation for $\lambda$ is 
uses the same notation for $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$ as in your problem.

There are no derivations, but you can check your results.

Comment: But according to it $c=\sqrt{(\frac{a^2}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{b^2}{\sigma_2^2})}$. Mine case is slightly different but yes you observation is very close.

Comment: OK, but just adjust the notation? Seems still in the same family.